# Intermediate result storage for Spring Batch processing REST service

Tags: spring, rest, spring-batch

I would like to get a document out of REST service, process with Spring Batch and then send to other REST service without saving anything to any database.

Considering each `Step` needs it's `ItemReader` and `ItemWriter`, I imagine I would need to implement one `ItemReader` that will download documents from input service, one `ItemWriter` that will somehow store intermediate results in memory, then an `ItemReader` that will read such results from memory for next steps and the last `ItemWriter` that will send results once all processing is done.

Would that be a good approach or does anyone have any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to get a document out of REST service, process with Spring Batch and then send to other REST service

You can do it in one chunk-oriented step. The reader to get data from the REST service, a processor to process data and a write to post/put data to the other REST service.

> without saving anything to any database.

Even though you don't want to save anything to a database (I guess you mean to a separate database server), you can still use an in-memory database and save intermediate processing results to a staging table. A first step would get the data from the REST service, process it and write it to the staging table. The second step reads data from the staging table and send it to the second REST service. The advantage of this technique is that you can do aggregation on processing results on the staging table before starting the second step.

> Would that be a good approach or does anyone have any better ideas?

A third way to do it is to use a staging in-memory `java.util.Queue`. Here, you can use two steps like with the staging table but using the queue as the staging storage.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if i run two or more such jobs at the same time? I guess i’ll have to use locking ob the table, which might affect performance. What about storing data in job context? Is it possible via ItemProcessor interface? I need to have more than one processor btw

Comment: no need for locking, you can have a staging table per job instance, or a discriminator column to distinguish between records. Storing data in job context is not recommended if the data is big enough because the execution context end up serialized and persisted in the database.

Comment: You mean the context is persisted after the job is done?

Comment: no, the step execution context is persisted after each chunk, whereas the job execution context is persisted after each step. Please refer to last paragraph of this section: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/domain.html#executioncontext.